# Deleting old kernel modules manually

Tags: 14.04, kernel

Basically I like to have a "clean" system; so I run the ubuntu-tweak janitor from time to time to delete the old kernels. Today I did some manual checking and found the subdirectory `3.13.0-49-generic` within `/lib/modules`, That is fine it is my current kernel on 14.04; and yes, I want all the modules in there.

But then there are two older subdirectories `3.13.0-32-generic` and `3.8.0-31-generic` that contain various files like `modules.alias`, etc; and in the 3.8 directory, some really old vbox ko files.

Also when I run `dkms status` I am told:

```
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-29-generic, x86_64: built
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-49-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I have two questions:

1. I assume it is safe to just delete the last two directories?
2. Why is the janitor not deleting that older module for `bbswitch`; and how would I delete it manually?

Comment: Use `dpkg -S` to determine if they were added by packages, and if so, remove those packages.

Comment: @muru So you are basically saying: if the "dpkg -S /lib/modules/..../one.of.my.files is giving "dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern ...." then there is no package "owning" these files? I see; the 3.13 files seem to be clean; whereas the 3.8 files ... belong to the virtualbox-4.3 package.

Comment: So, the 3.13 ones wasn't owned by any package? :O

Comment: Had you upgraded or re-installed from a previous release without prior cleaning up old kernels?

Comment: @muru Correct. The 3.8 directory comes and goes with the virtualbox package.

Comment: @Takkat No. My 14.04 install was a "fresh" one; no upgrades.